# Dynamically changing the content of a dropdown list based up on a selected button

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a ng-options dropdown list that is common for three buttons on a single view meaning, this same dropdown is shown when user clicks any button, but the data populated in the dropdown should change based up on the button selected. I am using asp.net MVC view on which these buttons are displayed. The data for the dropdown gets from a JSON object with three properties as shown below. Based on the selection of the button the property from this object should be populated on the dropdown list.

Method in asp.net mvc controller:

```
public JsonResult GetDetails()
{ 
  var response = new { Names = names, 
                       CustomerDepartments = depts,
                        FilteredData = deptSubSet 
                     };
  return Json(response, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet();
}
```

In the below code for drop down list, the filteredData property should be changed to either names or customerDepartments shown above in the method that returns JSON object with three properties based up on user selection, how to implement a filter or a conditional statement on ng-options based on the button click or the selected action by the user. The selected action is stored in a method in angular controller and thats returned to MVC view as controller.SelectedAction.

```
  If controller.selectedaction=button1.click()
  ng-options="temp.Name as temp.Name for temp in          
 Controller.Method2.FilteredData

  If controller.selectedaction=button2.click
     ng-options="temp.Name as temp.Name for temp in          
    Controller.Method2.CustomerDepartments

   <select class="form-control" ng-      model="Controller.Method1.Dropdown1"
 ng-options="temp.Name as temp.Name for temp in          
 Controller.Method2.FilteredData"><option value="">Select a Value</option>
```

Comment: your question is not so clear to understand , can you elaborate the conditions , what results you want at what condition. make more code visibility of view and, show the conditions based on some practical data.

Comment: @viplock I included if conditions, based up on button click the same drop down should populate different day that is being return as properties from a json object...let me know if it's not clear yet...

Comment: whatever code you have provided above, what is the issue with that.?

Comment: how can i implement the same in ng-options, i have an mvc view or a cshtml page which has this drop down and the content of the dropdown should be changed based on the button click, there are three different buttons when ever user clicks each one corresponding data should be displayed, how can i achieve this, using an if condition in ng-options or if condition is cshtml page?